# Restructure Data from Long to Wide Format

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to use a data step and an array to convert from a long format to a wide format. Originally my table was in the wide format and I figured out how to make it in the long format but now I need to use an array to make it wide again. When I run my code of the last data step I get a table with empty Expense1, Expense2, Expense 3 etc. columns. My table needs to look like this but with nine Hotels and six Expense columns.

| Resort | Expense1 | Expense2 | Expense3 | Expense 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOTEL1 | $165.89 | $45.50 | $78.00 | $56.25 |
| HOTEL2 | $215.32 | $64.00 | $54.00 | $62.50 |

The long table looks like this but there are nine hotels.

| Resort | Expense ID | Expense |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HOTEL1 | 1 | $165.89 |
| HOTEL1 | 2 | $45.50 |
| HOTEL1 | 3 | $78.00 |

Here is my code but the last datastep is me attempting to convert it from long to wide.

```
proc import datafile="/home/u54324957/The 
Files/Hotels.xlsx" out=Sheet1 
    dbms=xlsx replace;
data Hotels;
set Sheet1;
array TheExpense(*) Expense1-Expense6;
array Peak(6) PeakExpense1-PeakExpense6;

do i=1 to 6;
    Peak(i)=TheExpense(i) * 1.25;
    drop i;
    drop Expense1-Expense6;
    format PeakExpense1-PeakExpense6 
dollar7.2;
end;
run;
title "Peak Season Resort Pricing";

proc print data=Hotels noobs;
run;
data Hotels1;
set Sheet1;
array Hotels(*) Expense1-Expense6;
do ExpenseID=1 to 6;
Expense = Hotels(ExpenseID);
drop Expense1-Expense6;
output;
end;
run;
title "Restructure Data from Wide to Long 
Format";
proc print data=Hotels1 noobs;
format Expense dollar7.2;
run;
proc sort data=Hotels1;
by ExpenseID;
run;
data Hotels2;
set Hotels1;
array Hotels(*) Expense1-Expense6;
retain Expense1-Expense3;
by ExpenseID;
if first.ExpenseID then i=0;
i+1;
if last.ExpenseID then output;
run;
proc print data=Hotels2;
run;
```

Any ideas for how I can fill in these empty columns with values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array based transposition by group can be accomplished as follows:

```
data wide(keep=resort expense1-expense6);

  if 0 then set tall (keep=resort); * prep PDV with resort variable;

  array expenses expenses1-expenses6; * prep PDV with wide variables;
  
  * reset array to zeroes, resorts without a specific expenseID will have a 0;
  do index = 1 to dim(expenses);
    expenses[index] = 0;
  end;

  * if you want missing values instead of zeroes;
  * call missing (of expenses(*));

  * dow loop, iterate down the by group;
  do until (last.resort);
    set tall;
    by resort;
    expenses[expenseID] = expense;
  end;

  *implicit output, one row per resort;
run;
```